# Usage of DbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to make DB connection using constructor

DbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)

but i dont want to do it using application config file. like this

line in config file

```
  <add name="DBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DB.csdl|
    res://*/DB.ssdl|res://*/DB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
    provider connection string=&quot;data source=SERVER;
    initialcatalog=DB;persist security info=True;
    user id=XXX;password=YYY;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
    App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

and line in code

```
public DBEntities() : base("name=DBEntities"){}
```

instate i want something like this directly in code

```
 public DBEntities() : base("connectionString=metadata=
 res://*/DB.csdl|res://*/DB.ssdl|res://*/DB.msl;
 provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;
 data source=SERVER;initial catalog=DB;
persist security info=True;
userid=XXX;password=YYY;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
App=EntityFramework&quot;"){}
```

if I try so, I have the 'System.ArgumentException': Keyword not supported: 'connectionstring'.

It is possible? How to do what i want?

Comment: Have you tried doing it?

Comment: Yes. result in question update

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem seems to be twofold:

1. You have included the attribute name `connectionString` in the connection string
2. The " needs to be replaced with '

The correct code should then become:

```
public DBEntities()
    : base("metadata=res://*/DB.csdl|res://*/DB.ssdl|res://*/DB.msl;provider=System.Data.Sq‌​‌​lClient;provider connection string='data source=SERVER;initial catalog=DB;persist security info=True;userid=XXX;password=YYY;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramew‌​‌​ork'")
{}
```

You can look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) for more details of the elements a connection string consists of, and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716756%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more details on Entity Framework connection string.

***Old anwers, for reference:***

The problem seems to be that you are including everything the web.config uses to define a connection string. The connection string is itself only what is contained between the quotation marks after the attribute connectionString, in your case `data source=SERVER;initial catalog=DB;persist security info=True;userid=XXX;password=YYY;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework`.

Try this instead:

```
public DBEntities() : base("data source=SERVER;initial catalog=DB;
  persist security info=True;
  userid=XXX;password=YYY;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
  App=EntityFramework"){}
```

Also, you can look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) for more details of the elements a connection string consists of.

Comment: No. I have this 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException'

Comment: Ah, code first which generates tables? Then you need more, I think the following: `metadata=res://*/DB.csdl|res://*/DB.ssdl|res://*/DB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SERVER;initial catalog=DB;persist security info=True;userid=XXX;password=YYY;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;`

Comment: Keyword not supported: 'data source'. :)

Comment: I think we are on the right track. Could you try with ' instead of &quot;? I.E., `metadata=res://*/DB.csdl|res://*/DB.ssdl|res://*/DB.msl;provider=System.Data.Sq‌​lClient;provider connection string='data source=SERVER;initial catalog=DB;persist security info=True;userid=XXX;password=YYY;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramew‌​ork'`

Comment: Great! Will update answer based on these comments :)

Answer (score 2):

In your `Model.Context.tt`, add the following under the constructor;

```
public <#=code.Escape(container)#>(string connStr)
    : base(connStr)
{
<#
if (!loader.IsLazyLoadingEnabled(container))
{
#>
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
<#
}

foreach (var entitySet in container.BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>())
{
// Note: the DbSet members are defined below such that the getter and
// setter always have the same accessibility as the DbSet definition
if (Accessibility.ForReadOnlyProperty(entitySet) != "public")
{
#>
    <#=codeStringGenerator.DbSetInitializer(entitySet)#>
<#
}
}
#>
}
```

After rebuilding, you will now have a second constructor taking a `string` argument `connStr`;

```
public DBEntities() : base("name=DBEntities"){}
public DBEntities(string connStr) : base(connStr){}
```

You can now create your own connection string in your code and pass it to the constructor. Example;

```
public string connStr = "your connection string";

using (var db = new DBEntities(connStr))
{
    //do things with db
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your connection string passed to constructor.
try this instead :

```
private const string _connectionString = @"data source=SERVER;initial catalog=DB;persist security info=True;user id=XXX;password=YYY;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
public DBEntities() : base(_connectionString)
{
}
```

Comment: I have this 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException' occurred in MapX.Model.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Code generated using the T4 templates for Database First and Model First development may not work correctly if used in Code First mode.